# "Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:" in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, handshake, sslhandshakeexception

I need to call an external API that returns the food's name and the food's image URL in JSON format. As shown below.

```
   "extendedIngredients": [
        {
            "id": 1001,
            "aisle": "Milk, Eggs, Other Dairy",
            "image": "butter-sliced.jpg",
            "consistency": "SOLID",
            "name": "butter",
            "nameClean": "butter",
            "original": "1 tbsp butter",
            "originalName": "butter",
            "amount": 1.0,
            "unit": "tbsp"
        }
      ]
```

I need to get the data from API and display in a table.
Here is my API to call the external API.

```
    @GetMapping("/view/searchdata")
public String getinfo(@ModelAttribute(name = "food") SearchDTO searchDTO,Model model){
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    Menu results = restTemplate.getForObject("https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/716429/information?apiKey=c5e52d1350634e50a46d48565164125f&includeNutrition=true", Menu.class);
    String obj= results.toString();


    model.addAttribute("response", results);
    return "result";
}
```

For the frontend I use thymleaf. Here is my frontend HTML code.

```
 <table>
            <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>aisle</th>
                <th>consistency</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>original</th>
                <th>originalName</th>
                <th>amount</th>
                <th>unit</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            <tr th:each="food: ${response.extendedIngredients}">
                <td th:text="${food.aisle}">aisle</td>
                <td th:text="${food.consistency}">consistency</td>
                <td th:text="${food.name}">name</td>
                <td th:text="${food.original}">original</td>
                <td th:text="${food.originalName}">toriginalNameitle</td>
                <td th:text="${food.amount}">amount</td>
                <td th:text="${food.unit}">unit</td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

And here is my "Menu" Class.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Menu {


//List<Results> results;
List<ExtendedIngredients> extendedIngredients;


}
```

And here is my "ExtendedIngredients" Class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ExtendedIngredients {

private String aisle;
private String consistency;
private String name;
private String nameClean;
private String original;
private String originalName;
private String amount;
private String unit;
}
```

First time I called my API this works. but When I reload the web page or try again. This gives an error. Then if I restart the java program again this works fine one time. If I reload the page it will give an error.

The error is shown below.

````
    ```I/O error on GET request for "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/716429/information": Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/716429/information": Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:791)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:717)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:340)
    at leticia.romeu.deliApp.controller.DeliController.getinfo(DeliController.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:670)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:279)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:181)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:163)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:782)```
````

I have added spring security for the authorization in this project. But I have not added anything related to SSL.

What was this Issue? And how to fix this? ANyone can help me with this I would be grateful.

Comment: *javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure* indicates problems with the certificate. Do you work with self sined certificates?

Comment: The issue is related to the connection with the API. SSL related issue, check if you are importing the certificate in the keystore

Comment: No, I have not done anything related to SSL.

Comment: Looks like the certificate you get from client is not correct or not setup is not done properly

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue. Im posting here for anyone's future reference.
The issue is with the SSL certification. So I disable the SSL certification.

Here are the imports.

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
```

Add the following code to the relevant class

```
private RestTemplate restTemplateconfig() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
        SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(csf).build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

        return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    }
```

And also add the following dependency to your POM.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.13</version>
</dependency>
```